# Separate Menu for Duplicate and on-hold questions

Tags: feature-request

Whenever we go through questions on this platform, we find a few **duplicate** and/or **on-hold** questions that have few or no answers. At times, such questions can be a cause of distraction and disinterest for the users like us who want a solution for every little language-related difficulty.

[image]

IMO, ***a separate menu (as shown in the image) is now required that can include all such questions so that we can keep all the normal questions together without any disturbance of 'on-hold' or 'duplicate' questions.***

If moderators and other senior members of this platform want to create a separate menu for such questions, they should do it as soon as possible because many new members are joining on a daily basis and most of them are unaware of rules regarding asking and answering questions.

Comment: Aw... *disinterest* has a different meaning! :)

Comment: Moderator@ work on ELL! :)

Comment: I don't see the use of such list. Because 1) On hold questions can be improved and reopened. *They* are the questions that need the most care. And 2) You can always achieve that by including `duplicate:no` or `closed:no` in your searches. Hence as the nature of feature-requests suggests, I -1'd this. Sorry.

Comment: Duplicate questions have a link to the question they've duplicated, and usually those questions have good answers.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you can create this feature for yourself instead of waiting for the developers to decide whether it's needed. The interesting thing about searches in SE sites is that you can bookmark them so you can go directly to your customized view of the site.

If you search for "is:question closed:no" then click on "active" or "newest" or whatever you prefer, then bookmark that page, you will have a view customized to what you like to see. Here's an example with the "active" tab selected:

https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=is%3aquestion%20closed%3ano

You can even filter based on the number of answers or exclude or include tags - the search feature is pretty powerful. See [How do I search?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for more information.

Comment: Actually Colleen, `closed:no` suffices: Some search terms include others by default, so when I search for `hasaccepted:1` or `closed:yes` I do include `is:question`.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. I just repurposed one of my more specific searches - my point wasn't to provide the most efficient solution to the specific problem, but to show how you can use searches and bookmarks to customize your view of a SE site. closed:yes also returns only questions.